# docker tty command execute display

Tags: linux, docker, centos

Run container:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tty
/dev/pts/3
[root@localhost ~]# docker run -it nginx /bin/bash
root@bee12031f933:/# sleep 20
root@bee12031f933:/#
```

See:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tty
/dev/pts/2
[root@localhost ~]# w
 17:43:24 up 19 days, 45 min,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    192.168.1.22     16:24    1:01m  0.73s  0.00s sleep 20
root     pts/1    192.168.1.22     11:31    1:02m  4.92s  4.65s docker run -it centos:7.7.1908
root     pts/2    192.168.1.22     16:31    4.00s  0.70s  0.01s w
root     pts/3    192.168.1.22     15:09    4.00s  0.25s  0.07s docker run -it nginx /bin/bash
root     pts/4    192.168.1.22     16:41   44.00s  0.06s  0.06s -bash
```

Example picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FttUR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YBfE.png)

docker container running in pts/3, execute command in container "sleep 20". then,  i execute command "w" on the external host, display command "sleep 20" is executed in pts/0,  what's the reason ?

why do external hosts display commands executed in containers ?

Answer (score 0):

docker is similar to how LXC works. It allows sandboxing processes from one another, and controlling their resource allocations.

Since the resources are "separated", the system will show the information based on what it knows.

```
myuser@localhost: ~ $ tty
/dev/pts/1
myuser@localhost: ~ $ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:18.04 bash
root@36ed505961f4:/# tty
/dev/pts/0
```

Check the [Kernel Namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#kernel-namespaces) for more info.

Comment: executing the command "w" on an external host will display the commands in the container. Why ?

Comment: I don't have this behavior and I tried the command on both ubuntu and suse machines

Comment: Anyway you can see the commands when executing `ps auxwww` and the reason is that the docker containers are sandboxed while the host can still see everything (and kill the process if you're using the right user). Docker is not a VM solution.

Comment: I suggest to check how the kernel namespaces can be used.